# SpaCy not filling dataframe in pandas along expected lines

Tags: pandas, dataframe, spacy

I have created the following dataset with the help of spaCy and Python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import spacy
from spacy.util import minibatch, compounding
from spacy.lang.en import English
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Sentence': ["Hello Xime", "iPhone is an Apple Phone", "New Delhi is the Capital 
of India"] })
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
df["Col1"] = [nlp(i).ents for i  in df["Sentence"]]
df["lab"] = [[(ent.label_) for ent in ents] for ents in df["Col1"]]
print (df)
```

The following dataset is the result

[image]

I have created two columns in df namely GPE and ORG

```
df[["GPE", "ORG"]]=pd.DataFrame([[np.nan,np.nan ]], index=df.index)
```

Next I have tried the following code to assign values in Col1  under GPE and ORG respectively if the associated labels are GPE and ORG

I have also tried the following code and the loop runs.

```
list1=["GPE", "ORG"]##CREATED A LIST
for i in list1 :df[i]= [[(ent.text) for ent in ents if ent.label_==i] for ents in df["Col1"]]
```

This yields the following image(expected outcome)

[image]

Now I have tried

```
 for i in list1:
 df[i]= [[[(ent.text) for ent in ents if ent.label_==i] for ents in j ] for nlp(j) in  
 df["Sentence"]]
```

This yields the following error

```
  SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

I request someone to point me in the right direction. Am unable to get an idea as to where I am making a mistake

Comment: What is `j`? Show [reprex] leading to your error message

Comment: try this under your for look: `df[i] = [[ent.text for ent in nlp(j).ents if ent.label_ == i] for j in df["Sentence"]]`

Comment: Awesome. Shifting the nlp function is the step.

Comment: Works. Can you add this as an answer so that I can accept the same